# feature blending in ArcGIS online

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-online

I'm attempting to configure the blending tool in ArcGIS Online, but it appears that only layer blending is available, unlike in ArcGIS Pro where there's feature blending. Have there been any adjustments made to include feature blending in ArcGIS Online?

I can see layer blending options in Arcgis online but not feature blending options.